# RSpec: How to test for a boolean return type?

Tags: rspec, boolean

I'm using RSpec to test an API. I want to specify that one particular endpoint returns a boolean value, either `true` or `false`. This is an API to be used by other systems and languages, and so it's important for it to be an actual boolean, not merely something that Ruby will evaluate to `false` or `true`.

But I don't see a way to do this because there's no `Boolean` type in Ruby.

Comment: Does the API return a string? JSON? Seems like you should be testing the same thing that the API consumer will see, e.g. 'true' is true.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
expect(variable).to be_in([true, false])
```

Comment: Lots of good answers to my question here. Personally, I like this one the most because it's simple and clear.

Comment: didn't work here: `expected true to respond to 'in?'`

Comment: @brauliobo you need rails (or at least active support)

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem. This is what I came up with:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_boolean do
  match do |actual|
    expect(actual).to be_in([true, false])
  end
end
```

See: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/custom-matchers

It can be used like so:

```
it 'is boolean' do
  expect(true).to be_boolean
end
```

Comment: Upvoted for defining a general-purpose, highly reusable solution to the OP that follows RSpec's conventions. The only thing I would personally change would be to use @tomasz's `be_in([true, false])` conditional instead of the `satisfy` block, just because it's so concise and straightforward.

Comment: Good idea! Done.

Answer (score 22):

In more recent rspec versions one can use compound matchers:

```
expect(thing).to be(true).or be(false)
```

Comment: Nice. Without the space, `be(true).or(be(false))`, this also works with the `match` matcher (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-99/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher).

Answer (score 8):

How about a combination of the above?

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_boolean do
  match do |value|
    [true, false].include? value
  end
end
```

usage:

```
expect(something).to be_boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

While Ruby doesn't have a `Boolean` class, it does have [TrueClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/TrueClass.html) and [FalseClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/FalseClass.html), of which `true` and `false` are the only instances.  I'm sure you could test against either of those two and be good to go.

```
true.is_a? TrueClass # => true
(1 == 1).is_a? TrueClass # => true
1.is_a? TrueClass # => false

false.is_a? FalseClass # => true
(1 == 2).is_a? FalseClass # => true
nil.is_a? FalseClass # => false
```

Comment: What would the complete spec look like that incorporates both?

Comment: It wouldn't be anything special, just get the result from your API and do something like: `[TrueClass, FalseClass].should include(result.class)` or even `(result.is_a? TrueClass || result.is_a? FalseClass).should be_true`.

Comment: [TrueClass, FalseClass].should include(result.class) or even (result.is_a? TrueClass || result.is_a? FalseClass).should be_true  have syntax error in rspec2 and not working.

Answer (score 2):

It's a long time later, but here's what I settled on:

```
foo.should satisfy {|x| [true, false].map(&:object_id).include? x.object_id}
```

This works because true and false only have one instance. Also, more of a curiosity, but they also always have the same instance id.

Answer (score 1):

Add the gem rspec_boolean to your Gemfile in the group :development, :test:

**gem 'rspec_boolean'**

And than use it like:

**expect(val.is_done).to be_boolean**